# EWS TimeZoneDefinitions: For a timezone, how to calculate UTC offset at present time

Tags: python, timezone, exchangewebservices

I am creating an application that uses [EWS APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) to syncs users' 
exchange calendars to their mobile device. A calendar event fetched from exchange server contains the timezone info for the start-time and end-time of this event. As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff406132(v=exchg.140).aspx) a timezone item in EWS response is represented as below:

```
      <m:TimeZoneDefinitions>
        <t:TimeZoneDefinition Name="(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)" Id="Eastern Standard Time">
          <t:Periods>
            <t:Period Bias="PT5H" Name="Standard" Id="trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2006-Standard"/>
            <t:Period Bias="PT4H" Name="Daylight" Id="trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2006-Daylight"/>
            <t:Period Bias="PT5H" Name="Standard" Id="trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2007-Standard"/>
            <t:Period Bias="PT4H" Name="Daylight" Id="trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2007-Daylight"/>
          </t:Periods>
          <t:TransitionsGroups>
            <t:TransitionsGroup Id="0">
              <t:RecurringDayTransition>
                <t:To Kind="Period">trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2006-Daylight</t:To>
                <t:TimeOffset>PT2H</t:TimeOffset>
                <t:Month>4</t:Month>
                <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
                <t:Occurrence>1</t:Occurrence>
              </t:RecurringDayTransition>
              <t:RecurringDayTransition>
                <t:To Kind="Period">trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2006-Standard</t:To>
                <t:TimeOffset>PT2H</t:TimeOffset>
                <t:Month>10</t:Month>
                <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
                <t:Occurrence>-1</t:Occurrence>
              </t:RecurringDayTransition>
            </t:TransitionsGroup>
            <t:TransitionsGroup Id="1">
              <t:RecurringDayTransition>
                <t:To Kind="Period">trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2007-Daylight</t:To>
                <t:TimeOffset>PT2H</t:TimeOffset>
                <t:Month>3</t:Month>
                <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
                <t:Occurrence>2</t:Occurrence>
              </t:RecurringDayTransition>
              <t:RecurringDayTransition>
                <t:To Kind="Period">trule:Microsoft/Registry/Eastern Standard Time/2007-Standard</t:To>
                <t:TimeOffset>PT2H</t:TimeOffset>
                <t:Month>11</t:Month>
                <t:DayOfWeek>Sunday</t:DayOfWeek>
                <t:Occurrence>1</t:Occurrence>
              </t:RecurringDayTransition>
            </t:TransitionsGroup>
          </t:TransitionsGroups>
          <t:Transitions>
            <t:Transition>
              <t:To Kind="Group">0</t:To>
            </t:Transition>
            <t:AbsoluteDateTransition>
              <t:To Kind="Group">1</t:To>
              <t:DateTime>2007-01-01T00:00:00</t:DateTime>
            </t:AbsoluteDateTransition>
          </t:Transitions>
        </t:TimeZoneDefinition>
      </m:TimeZoneDefinitions>
```

What I need is:
From the TimeZoneDefinition XML above, at present what is the time offset from UTC?

Can anyone please explain me the algorithm I should follow to calculate it. Is there any existing library (python) that does this?

Comment: Why not just get it from the xml?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract it from the XML. But the XML above looks cryptic. I was hoping if some one alreday knows the steps to follow in order to extract the offset from the XML.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options.  The first would be my preferred recommendation:

1. Install the [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) and [pytz](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz) packages.
2. Extract the `Id` element of the XML (or perhaps you have it in the event data already and can eliminate an extra web service call).  In the example above, the Windows time zone Id is `"Eastern Standard Time"`.

   ```
   import lxml.etree as et
   xml = et.fromstring(open("in.xml").read())
   windowsTimeZoneId = xml.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'TimeZoneDefinition']/@Id")
   ```

   *(Thanks to [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) for the above XML extraction snippet.)*
3. Use tzlocal to resolve the IANA time zone from the Windows time zone ID, taking advantage of the CLDR-based Windows-to-IANA mapping file included with this library.

   ```
   from tzlocal.windows_tz import win_tz
   ianaTimeZoneId = win_tz.get(windowsTimeZoneId)
   ```

   This should give you `"America/New_York"`.
4. Use pytz with the resulting time zone identifier

   ```
   from datetime import datetime
   import pytz
   tz = pytz.timezone(ianaTimeZoneId)
   now = datetime.now(tz)
   ```

The other option is to algorithmically parse the XML to determine the offset for the time in question.  I'll give you a breakdown of the steps involved (someone else can supply the code if desired):

1. Get the current date and time - since you wanted the *current* offset.  (Though recognize it may indeed be different for another date and time.)  You'll need to get the *local* time relevant to the time zone in question, as that is the basis for how these rules are defined (that alone may involve pytz and tzlocal).
2. Examine the `Transitions` section and find the one that's applicable.  In your example, the first rule is a catch-all, the second is valid from 2007 forward, so the second one is applicable to the current time.  It is marked as Group 1.
3. Find the `TransitionGroup` matching the number from the previous step (`TransitionGroup Id="1"`).  Calculate the dates within the current year gien the `Month`, `DayOfWeek`, and `Occurrence` values.  Apply the `TimeOffset` value from midnight to get the time-of-day of the transition (`00:00` + `PT2H` == `2:00 AM` in this case).
4. Determine which `Period` is applicable, based on whether the date in question lies before or after each transition date.  Consider that in the Northern hemisphere, the transition to Daylight time occurs first, then the transition to Standard time occurs later.  In the Southern hemisphere, it's the opposite.  The logic here may get tricky, and you have to consider the edge cases of having a local time that falls into the spring-forward "gap", or one that appears twice in the fall-back "overlap".
5. Use the `Period` value's `Bias` property as the offset, inverting the sign.  In this case, `PT5H` is UTC-5, and `PT4H` is UTC-4.

As you can see, this is quite complex, and probably not something that could be written cleanly as an answer on this site.  Someone wanting to write a library for this could certainly go through these steps to resolve the offset from the XML data directly - but the first option is *much* easier - and more reliable when you consider that you have full control over updating the time zone data yourself.

Comment: I tried tzlocal library approach. It fails for many users because the Id element of the XML was 
1. empty OR 
2. some random string. ex: "tzone://Microsoft/Utc", "GMT+00:00", "India Time" OR
3. contains Unicode characters that pytz and tzlocal cannot handle.

I realised that I can not rely on the ID, it can be any random string and the right thing to do is to parse the timezone definition. I ended up writing a parser for the timezone definition provided in the EWS response.

Comment: @Varun - If you can share the solution, please do.  You can add it in an answer to this question.  Thank!